# TinyMCE - dynamic add/remove multiple times

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm working on some web application that uses tinyMCE. I use regular (non-jQuery version) of TinyMCE 3, but I use jQuery to add and remove it from the textarea.

The textarea itself is populated first by html from the div, and then the tinymce control is added. (later that content is either saved to db or discarded by a form submit.

Now - this all basically works, but problem I have is that once tinyMCE is added, and then removed once, it's stuck, and won't add the control a second time.

I use this to load the tinyMCE

```
$(".mcmsmdl_pagestatic_editpopup").on('click',function(){
            var smi = $(this).data('sectionmoduleindex');
            var content = $('#mcmsmdl_pagestatic_content_'+smi).html();
            $('#popup_module_pagestatic').data('sectionmoduleindex',smi);
            $('#mcmsmdl_pagestatic_content_textarea').val(content);
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'mcmsmdl_pagestatic_content_textarea');
            displayPopup('module_pagestatic',true);
        });
```

Note: displayPopup() is a function to just show the container that holds the form with tinyMce.

The tinyMce is removed on popup closing with:

```
$(".popup_shadow_module_pagestatic").on('click',function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'mcmsmdl_pagestatic_content_textarea');
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'mcmsmdl_pagestatic_content_textarea');
            displayPopup('module_pagestatic',false);
        });
```

I checked - and it is unloaded after the second code.
Any ideas why won't it re-add the tinyMCE control when calling the same (first) code again?

**EDIT:**
After checking with console:
It's indeed loaded and unloaded correctly, but second loading produces a "Too much recursion" error. It seems that somewhere in tinyMCE code it goes in an infinite loop...

**EDIT2**
As Thariama suggested, I changed the code to first display the textarea and then add the control, and now I get different errors:

in tinymce.js:

> TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined

in editor_plugin.js:

> NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005
>   (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)[nsIDOMNavigator.userAgent]

**EDIT3**
Errors from edit2 were because the page was refreshed, and not loaded clean. When loaded clean, the Too Much Recursion error is shown again...

**EDIT4**
All the problems seem to be fixed by removing the iBrowser plugin. - now I need to find another free image uploader... :(

Comment: are you really sure it is unloaded? can you log this to console and tell me the ids of the result: tinymce.editors

Comment: Checked with console log - it is really unloading - at first it's empty ([ ]), on open - it is an object, and later again empty

Comment: Hmmm... looked a bit more, and there's an error in console after trying to open second time -> "Too much recursion" - But I don't see a loop anywhere...

Comment: ok, the editor shut down seems to work, but that javascript error should not appear

Comment: is the textarea visible when you try to init the editor?

Comment: It wasn't, - now I tried to first display it, and then add the editor - still no change, but now there's "TypeError: this.getDoc(...) is undefined" in tinymce.js,  and "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMNavigator.userAgent]" in editor_plugin.js

Comment: NS_ERROR_FAILURE is a browser error. "this.getDoc(...) is undefined" can appear if you just reload your page - it is a bug in the tinymce core (error unloading tinymce). just naviagate to your page from the regular website menu and this error won't occur

Comment: You're right - it was a refresh (forgotten)... But still, second adding pops back the too much recursion error...

Comment: hmm, without a live example this is difficult to solve